# <a href> to external link returns link/Error in webapp, even though the server is not dead

Tags: c#, html, web-frontend

I've got 3 links in the header of a .net C# MVC, with the following .cshtml file:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="manag-nav">
    <a class="manag-page" href="https://EXAMPLE-LINK.com/Account">@Resources.label-A</a>
    <a class="manag-page" href="https://backoffice.EXAMPLE-LINK.com/Sitefinity">@Resources.label-B</a>
    <a class="manag-page website-page" href="http://www.EXAMPLE-LINK.com">@Resources.label-C</a>
</div>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo.png")" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="user-login">

</div>
```

Label1 and label3 links work fine, but my 2nd link, label2, when you click it, it returns "http://backoffice.blabla.com/Error" instead of "http://backoffice.blabla.com/Sitefinity".

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I forgot to mention that when I go to this link directly, it works. Or when I write the link for this url in a simple .html file, it also works. It just stops working in the project.

Comment: That's because the URL is dead and the server is redirecting you. It's nothing to do with your code - other than having a bad URL

Comment: It's dead when I try it, too

Comment: The server is not dead, because if I insert this piece of code in a simple .html file using notepad, it goes to the link without any problem. 

But if I insert this link in my .cshtml file project, it returns the link with /Error, which is really strange.

Comment: That's because it is an example link, I didn't put the real ones

Comment: I edited my initial post to avoid any further confusion. Those links are merely an example, based on the real ones

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are already logged in with a user and when you try to access /Sitefinity that user might not have backend access permissions, or is redirected to another page based on its role and there is an issue with that page, etc.

Long and short - make sure you are not logged in to Sitefinity and then try the link.

If you still face the issue - then better examine the rendered html output - it may have been modified by an external javascript, or there might be a javascript click handler for that html element, could be many things.